# scrolling menu bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, uitabbar

I am designing an app and I am thinking of adding a scrolling menu bar in app.I have tried JSScrollableTabBar from

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsscrollabletabbar

but it just crashes when I check the demo that is uploaded on github !

Comment: And what do you want us to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this problem. Replace below line in  ScrollableTabBarViewController.m file.

**JSTabItem *item = [[JSTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i]];**

Replace with

**JSTabItem *item = [[JSTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i] andColor:[UIColor redColor] andTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];**